How to Pivot Table information to show notes and filter by sum value
I have data with 4 columns. A date column, Full Name column, Hours Worked column and a Memo column. The first three columns all contain data but the last (Memo) is often blank. I want to build a pivot table that sums the values of the hours for each name and filter to show only those under 40 total. I then want to show all the Memos for each person in the filtered list and do not want to show blanks. Attached is an image of a very simplified version.



Timecard Date
Full Name
Hours
Memo




5/6/2024
Albert, James
4.00
Sick


5/6/2024
Albert, James
4.00



5/6/2024
Albert, James
(4.00)



5/6/2024
Albert, James
(4.00)



5/6/2024
Albert, James
4.00
Left Early


5/6/2024
Albert, James
4.00



5/7/2024
Albert, James
1.00



5/6/2024
Beaver, Jack
4.00



5/6/2024
Beaver, Jack
4.00
PTO


5/6/2024
Beaver, Jack
2.00



5/7/2024
Beaver, Jack
8.00



5/7/2024
Beaver, Jack
2.00



5/8/2024
Beaver, Jack
3.00



5/8/2024
Beaver, Jack
5.00
Van 123


5/8/2024
Beaver, Jack
2.00



5/9/2024
Beaver, Jack
2.00



5/9/2024
Beaver, Jack
2.00



5/10/2024
Beaver, Jack
1.00



5/10/2024
Beaver, Jack
2.00



5/10/2024
Beaver, Jack
2.00



5/6/2024
Smith, Kyle
8.00



5/7/2024
Smith, Kyle
5.00



5/7/2024
Smith, Kyle
3.00
No hours


5/8/2024
Smith, Kyle
4.00



5/8/2024
Smith, Kyle
4.00



5/9/2024
Smith, Kyle
1.00



5/9/2024
Smith, Kyle
3.50



5/9/2024
Smith, Kyle
3.50



5/10/2024
Smith, Kyle
4.00



5/10/2024
Smith, Kyle
4.00



5/11/2024
Smith, Kyle
8.00




I've tried building a pivot table with Top row being full name, second row being memo, filtering for the non-blank memos and then adding the hours to the values filed but it only gives me the hours to the instances where a memo was present. I have access to a separate list of people who are under 40 hours and could use that to filter the names column but do not know how to filter via a list.

Please do some research, like is mentioned in How to ask, then use [edit] , to provide data as TEXT, not as IMAGE (see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?), BTW: Welcome to stackoverflow, the place to get help (not always answers, because there is not free-code-writing!) when providing a [mre]

A pivot is (to my knowledge) mostly created from a SQL Database. Can you share a [DBFIDDLE[(https://dbfiddle.uk/qQMKswaJ) of this data, and what your tried ?
